# Words for specific omnipotent qualities

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a story about a powerful god with specific abilities, which are:

- he can hear everything, no matter how far, and he can read minds
- he always knows where someone is or who is nearby, but he can't see everything (he does have exceptional eye sight though)
- he is a "person" in that he is only one presence, he's not someone who is everywhere, can see everything and knows everything
- he can't make impossible things happen (he can't cure someone's blindness for example), but he is powerful in that he has immense *physical* strength, enough to destroy a planet if he wishes to

Obviously, I don't expect there to be a word that matches exactly those very specific points, but I hope there is a word for each point at least.

Answer (score 1):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/godlike):

**godlike**:  resembling or having the qualities of God or a god

> In taking on the full power of a sun, at the risk of his life, in
>   order to forge a weapon to defeat Thanos, Thor displays his full
>   **godlike** potential.

There's also superhuman, phenomenal, incredible, awesome, titanic, terrible...

You'd have to use it in a phrase: "godlike strength" "godlike hearing"

Answer (score 1):

I think **superhuman** fit this question:  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/superhuman)

> 1. Above or beyond the human; preternatural or supernatural.
> 2. Beyond ordinary or normal human ability, power, or experience

As in:

> Advances in science, engineering and biotechnology will produce a
>   superhuman in the near future. Scientific American Aug 2, 2018

Answer (score 0):

This person could well be a ***[demigod](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demigod?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)***.

> ***demigod***
>   1 : a mythological being with more power than a mortal but less than a god
>   2 : a person so outstanding as to seem to approach the divine
>   *the demigods of jazz*

Comment: I doubt that this is the word OP is looking for, since they say their character is a god in the first sentence of the question.

Comment: @Laurel Granted. However, in the sense that he's not omnipotent nor omniscient, and takes the form of a person, the closer description might be of one that is a demigod and not a god

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ***telepathic*** for the first three points you made. This adjective also avoids including "god" or "human" in it. I believe since you specifically referred to the character as a "god", using the word "godlike", "demigod", or "superhuman" would misvalue the character or unhelpful in description.

Here are some definitions of telepathy/telepathic:

- Google: supposedly capable of transmitting thoughts to other people and of knowing their thoughts; psychic.
- Merriam-Webster: communication from one mind to another by extrasensory means
- Dictionary.com: communication between minds by some means other than sensory perception.

I think you still have to explain your god character's ability to readers though. The word encapsulates the three points, in my opinion, but it is ambiguous enough that I don't think readers will know the abilities precisely.

As for the last point, "can't make impossible things happen", I can't make a proper suggestion. ***Superhuman strength*** suggested by lbf above might be your best bet for that ability.